# Recover mysql database innodb 'table doesn't exist'

Tags: windows, mysql, database, innodb, database-restore

Our server crashed last week and we lost a lot of information. We were able to recover `.frm` files for the tables, `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1` and `ibdata1` but no `.ibd`.

I've tried the `innodb-force-recovery` on all levels 1 to 6 and a whole lot of other 'solutions' I've found online, without any success.

Right now I was trying to do it trhough a `mysqldump` and `restore` of the database but run into the same problem [Mathew over here](https://serverfault.com/questions/449201/recover-mysql-database-mysql-mysqldump-gives-table-database-tablename-doe?newreg=ee4023883b43454bb672ee010f7f1962).

[this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/449201/recover-mysql-database-mysql-mysqldump-gives-table-database-tablename-doe?newreg=ee4023883b43454bb672ee010f7f1962#449238) looks like it might work. My problem is, first - my server is Windows based, second - I lack the knowledge and skills to apply this on windows command line.

By any chance is there a similar solution for Windows

**edit**

we were not using `innodb_file_per_table` so all data should be stored on `ibdata1`

Comment: The inconsistent InnoDB dictionary yields "table doesn't exist" error. But there is another problem. A table's data are in a corresponding `.ibd` file. It makes no sense to try `mysqldump`. I would take an image from the disk and fetched table records. See https://twindb.com/take-image-from-corrupted-hard-drive/ and https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/ for some ideas

Comment: I've been talking to my colleagues this morning and they say we never had `.ibd` files because of not using `innodb_file_per_table` all data should be stored on `ibdata1`

Comment: If you have backups, you should restore from them.
If you have a disk corruption and no backups, first step is to image the disk using something like `ddrecue`. Then make copies of the image and try to fix the problem on those copies.

Comment: Time to finally think about getting a budget for a working backup!

Answer (score 0):

[This MySQL forum post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,47078,51428) looks like a success story, although a bit old. I remember a similar story of mine, on Linux. Windows platform doesn't matter here, MySQL data files structure is similar. No command line work is really needed. I assume your *Ibdata* file is not damaged in any way.

AFAIK you don't need *ib_logfile?* files at all, the forum post confirms that. The key operations here are:

1. a new installation of MySQL (use the same version);
2. manual recreation of **identically-named** databases, can be done from the latest backup dump if you have one;
3. disabling *innodb_file_per_table* in *my.cnf*, it's best to restore the old config;
4. replacing *Ibdata* in new installation with the recovered one.

After you start MySQL you should be able to browse and dump your data from InnoDB tables.