# Trying to recover MySQL database from a crashed server and I keep getting "mysqldump couldn't execute 'show create table doesn't exist (1146)"

Tags: mysql, innodb, opensuse, mariadb

My OpenSuse 13.1 server crashed and couldn't boot but I managed to connect the hard drive to another computer and copied the files in /var/lib/mysql

On a new installation, I followed the steps outlined in this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/449238/371208

However, when I attempt to start MySQL, I get this: "Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."

On running 'journalctl -xn', this is the output:

> -- Logs begin at Thu 2016-08-18 15:19:12 EAT, end at Thu 2016-08-18 17:49:02 EAT. -- Aug 18 17:45:13 CPMA dbus[600]: [system] Successfully
>   activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' Aug 18 17:46:28
>   CPMA dbus[600]: [system] Activating service
>   name='org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' (using servicehelper) Aug 18
>   17:46:28 CPMA dbus[600]: [system] Successfully activated service
>   'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' Aug 18 17:48:32 CPMA systemd[1]:
>   Starting LSB: Start the MySQL database server...
>   -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun with start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support:
>
> -- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up. Aug 18 17:49:02 CPMA mysql[6300]: Starting service MySQL warning: /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
>   didn't appear within 30 seconds Aug 18 17:49:02 CPMA mysql[6300]:
>   chmod: cannot access '/var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid': No such file or
>   directory Aug 18 17:49:02 CPMA mysql[6300]: ..failed Aug 18 17:49:02
>   CPMA systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited
>   status=1 Aug 18 17:49:02 CPMA systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start
>   the MySQL database server.
>   -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>   -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> ### -- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/catalog/be02cf6855d2428ba40df7e9d022f03d
>
> ### -- Unit mysql.service has failed.
>
> -- The result is failed. Aug 18 17:49:02 CPMA systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before! You're probably over thinking the problem. It's actually either a permissions problem, a missing files/folders, or a missing pid file. It's easier to diagnose the problem by becoming the mysql user with su (su -s /bin/bash mysqld) or sudo (sudo -u mysqld -i), since being the correct user will also expose permissions problems. Once you are the mysql user you should check that the directory `/var/run/mysql/` exists. It should also have a folder for each database (not table). Additionally check that the mysql user has rw access to /var/run/mysql* and /var/lib/mysql*.

Anyway permissions problems might be fixable with chown. Occasionally filesystem ownership/permissions information gets scrambled when the disk gets bad blocks, but could also just be that your mysql user has a different uid on the new machine.

Anyway sometimes mysql will complain and cause massive problems if the pid file is missing, so I would recreate it while logged into the machine as the mysql user. You want the pid of mysqld_safe to be in the file. If mysql is not running than just leave it blank I guess.

TL;DR: This really is exactly what it looks like (usually). If not, write back?

Comment: BTW if the disk is slightly scrambled, try to resist the urge to fsck it unless you really have to. Fsck can wipe out all your data by miscorrecting bad inodes for important directories.

Comment: BTW, as of version 5.2 (?) or so, if it was your innodb files causing the problem the behavior would be that the database server would start, your MyISAM tables would be ok and your InnoDB engine would be listed as offline in the output of SHOW ENGINE STATUS. I used to work for a company that used rsync to backup it's db servers (while they were running, it didn't work that great). I'm 99% sure it's a permissions issue.